# How do I resolve an error that says FredCK Editor undefined for proj visual web dev 2010?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying set up the FCKEditorV2 to use in a visual web dev 2010 vb.net proj. and receiving an error stating :

```
Element FCKEditor is not a known element.
enter code here<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Edit.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm2" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" Namespace="FredCK.FCKEditorV2" TagPrefix="FCKeditorV2"  %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div><FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="FCKeditor1" runat="server"></FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found a website that explains how to correctly install this editor on vs express.
Thought I would share this link in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/208_Integrating_FCKeditor_in_ASPNet_Websites_%E2%80%93_Part_1.aspx